# xcode shortcut - ctrl + 1-5 collide with spaces?

Tags: xcode

In Xcode, when you want to use shortcuts like ctrl + 2(show previous history). This will collide with your screen moving through spaces. You probably could do something in system settings... but maybe I am missing something?

Regards
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shourt cut of xcode
Go to Preferences -> Go to Key Bindings
Here you can find all short cut keys you can change the conflit shortcuts[image]

Comment: Thanks, though I knew that. I was hoping that osx and xcode was working together - so there would be a fn+ctrl+5 kind of trick.